# why can't I extract a tuple from Either projection inside for comprehension using pattern matching?

Tags: scala, either

Why does this work:

```scala
val somePair: Option[(String,String)] = Some(("John", "Doe"))
(for {
  pair <- somePair.toRight("Hello unknown!").right
} yield s"Hello ${pair._1} ${pair._2}!").merge
```

But this doesn't:

```scala
val somePair: Option[(String,String)] = Some(("John", "Doe"))
(for {
  (name,lastName) <- somePair.toRight("Hello unknown!").right
} yield s"Hello $name $lastName!").merge
```

**Edit:** 
I should add this is the error message: 
`Error:(43, 4) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: scala.util.Either[Nothing,(String, String)]
  (name,lastName) <- somePair.toRight("Hello unknown!").right
  ^`

Comment: This is a bug which is open since quite some time. Take a look at https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5589.

Comment: @Sebastian yep seems like it. you should have wrote it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Scala which is unfortunately open since quite some time.

Take a look at https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5589 for reference.

Answer (score -1):

This bug will fixed if you use https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for

After addind it to dependencies:
`(name,lastName) <- somePair` works as expected

Comment: f4x, please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: I have no idea what I shoud demonstrate - just add the library to dependencies and `(name,lastName) <- somePair` works as expected

Comment: What is the reason for the decrease rating of answer? I searched the recipe, I found it and shared. It is crazy for me that a simple constataion of problem: yes, there is a bug in the compiler has positive rating and the solution of the problem is negative. If I will be searching solution of the problem it will be confusing me.